# Raspberry Pi, ON turns the GPIO output off?

Tags: python, gpio

For some reason I'm having problems turning on and off outputs with my programs.
if i use the following the output turns on / off correctly

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(2, 1)
time.sleep(2)        
GPIO.output(2, 0)
```

but for some reason with my fish tank lighting program GPIO.output(2, 0) (or False) turns the relay ON!? and the same for the inverse

Here is my program have i called the output incorrectly?

```
# Lighting Program ---

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT)  # Lights

#Declair Lighting On/Off Times
on_time_Monday = open("monday_on.txt", 'r').read()
off_time_Monday = open("monday_off.txt", 'r').read()

on_time_Tuesday = open("tuesday_on.txt", 'r').read()
off_time_Tuesday = open("tuesday_off.txt", 'r').read()

on_time_Wednesday = open("wednesday_on.txt", 'r').read()
off_time_Wednesday = open("wednesday_off.txt", 'r').read()

on_time_Thursday = open("thursday_on.txt", 'r').read()
off_time_Thursday = open("thursday_off.txt", 'r').read()

on_time_Friday = open("friday_on.txt", 'r').read()
off_time_Friday = open("friday_off.txt", 'r').read()

on_time_Saturday = open("saturday_on.txt", 'r').read()
off_time_Saturday = open("saturday_off.txt", 'r').read()

on_time_Sunday = open("sunday_on.txt", 'r').read()
off_time_Sunday = open("sunday_off.txt", 'r').read()

#Find out what day of the week it is
day = datetime.datetime.now()
day_of_week = day.isoweekday()

#find out what time it is
Current_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(),'%H%M')

#Schedule on / off
if (day_of_week == 1) and (Current_time > on_time_Monday and Current_time < off_time_Monday) :
    Light_on_off = 1
elif (day_of_week == 2) and (Current_time > on_time_Tuesday and Current_time < off_time_Tuesday) :
    Light_on_off = 1
elif (day_of_week == 3) and (Current_time > on_time_Wednesday and Current_time < off_time_Wednesday) :
    Light_on_off = 1
elif (day_of_week == 4) and (Current_time > on_time_Thursday and Current_time < off_time_Thursday) :
    Light_on_off = 1
elif (day_of_week == 5) and (Current_time > on_time_Friday and Current_time < off_time_Friday) :
    Light_on_off = 1
elif (day_of_week == 6) and (Current_time > on_time_Saturday and Current_time < off_time_Saturday) :
    Light_on_off = 1
elif (day_of_week == 7) and (Current_time > on_time_Sunday and Current_time < off_time_Sunday) :
    Light_on_off = 1
else :
    Light_on_off = 0

#    CALL OUTPUTS ON / OFF
if Light_on_off == 1:
    GPIO.output(2, 0)
    print(Light_on_off, "_HIGH_")
else:
    GPIO.output(2, 1)
    print(Light_on_off, "_LOW_")
```

Comment: We don't know what your circuit looks like.

Comment: Why not use `cleanup` command for check each pins default state ?

Comment: without any circuit, the pins are providing high voltage when i set the GPIO to 0 and i have low voltage when i set the GPIO pin to 1 this only happens when i use the full program (above). But if i just make a small program to turn the output pin on and off i dont have any problem(top bit of code)